# How to send form data to a spreadsheet. Xls

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good morning people,

I have a form that did a site, but the form only sends the information filled in form for a site: http://submit.jotformz.com/submit/21933800226649/, I wanted the data filled in form should be saved in a spreadsheet . xls, every time someone fill out and send the new information be added automatically as of the line 10.

The code of my form is this:

```
  <script src="http://max.jotfor.ms/min/g=jotform?3.0.3715" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   JotForm.init();
</script>
<link href="http://max.jotfor.ms/min/g=formCss?3.0.3715" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://jotformz.com/css/styles/nova.css?3.0.3715" />
<style type="text/css">
    .form-label{
        width:150px !important;
    }
    .form-label-left{
        width:150px !important;
    }
    .form-line{
        padding-top:12px;
        padding-bottom:12px;
    }
    .form-label-right{
        width:150px !important;
    }
    .form-all{
        width:690px;
        color:#555 !important;
        font-family:'Lucida Grande';
        font-size:14px;
    }
</style>

<form class="jotform-form" action="http://submit.jotformz.com/submit/21933800226649/" method="post" name="form_21933800226649" id="21933800226649" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <input type="hidden" name="formID" value="21933800226649" />
  <div class="form-all">
    <ul class="form-section">
      <li class="form-line" id="id_1">
        <label class="form-label-left" id="label_1" for="input_1"> Nome: </label>
        <div id="cid_1" class="form-input">
          <input type="text" class="form-textbox" id="input_1" name="q1_nome" size="20" />
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="form-line" id="id_3">
        <label class="form-label-left" id="label_3" for="input_3"> Opções </label>
        <div id="cid_3" class="form-input">
          <div class="form-single-column"><span class="form-radio-item" style="clear:left;"><input type="radio" class="form-radio" id="input_3_0" name="q3_opcoes" value="Opção 1" />
              <label for="input_3_0"> Opção 1 </label></span><span class="clearfix"></span><span class="form-radio-item" style="clear:left;"><input type="radio" class="form-radio" id="input_3_1" name="q3_opcoes" value="Opção 2" />
              <label for="input_3_1"> Opção 2 </label></span><span class="clearfix"></span><span class="form-radio-item" style="clear:left;"><input type="radio" class="form-radio" id="input_3_2" name="q3_opcoes" value="Opção 3" />
              <label for="input_3_2"> Opção 3 </label></span><span class="clearfix"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="form-line" id="id_5">
        <label class="form-label-left" id="label_5" for="input_5"> Comentarios </label>
        <div id="cid_5" class="form-input">
          <textarea id="input_5" class="form-textarea" name="q5_comentarios" cols="40" rows="6"></textarea>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="form-line" id="id_4">
        <label class="form-label-left" id="label_4" for="input_4"> Idioma </label>
        <div id="cid_4" class="form-input">
          <select class="form-dropdown" style="width:150px" id="input_4" name="q4_idioma">
            <option>  </option>
            <option value="Portugues"> Portugues </option>
            <option value="Ingles"> Ingles </option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="form-line" id="id_2">
        <div id="cid_2" class="form-input-wide">
          <div style="margin-left:156px" class="form-buttons-wrapper">
            <button id="input_2" type="submit" class="form-submit-button">
              Enviar
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li style="display:none">
        Should be Empty:
        <input type="text" name="website" value="" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="simple_spc" name="simple_spc" value="21933800226649" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("si" + "mple" + "_spc").value = "21933800226649-21933800226649";
  </script>
</form>
```

I just need something simple ..
Could someone give a help?

Comment: In order for this to work, you're going to have to gather the information from the form and parse together a spreadsheet on the server.  What backend technology are you using (ASP.NET, php, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

How to [read form information](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php/) in PHP

How to [write information to an excel spreadsheet](http://www.lateralcode.com/excel-spreadsheets-php/) in PHP

Comment: Ok, but how do I do this for my form, send the data to a spreadsheet?
I do not understand ..

Comment: Read here: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php/   Then, take what you've learned from the two articles and put them together.

Comment: Thanks, but you would have no ready with a simple example form, and a spreadsheet working? So that I could create up this example because I do not quite understand php language, then do the code from the beginning is complicated, do not even know where to start.
Could you send me an example of a form field with a 3, which has a button to send, it goes straight to the worksheet?